# Error in logcat for RecyclerView setLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am getting error in the `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

Following are the logcat error popping up while entering into the activity:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.lenovo.skanda.QuoteList.onCreate(QuoteList.java:36)

**QuoteList.java**

```java
public class QuoteList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StorageReference storageRef;

    RecyclerView  mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_list);

        //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Quotes");
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewQuote);
       // mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Quotes");
    }





    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quote, QuoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quote, QuoteViewHolder>(
                        Quote.class,
                        R.layout.quote_row,
                        QuoteViewHolder.class,
                        mReference
                ) {

                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(QuoteViewHolder viewHolder , Quote model , int position) {

                     //   viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getQuotes(), model.getQuote_Author(), model.getImages());
                            viewHolder.setQuotes(model.getQuotes());
                            viewHolder.setQuoteAuthor(model.getQuote_Author());


                    }
                };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    public static class QuoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public QuoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setQuotes(String Quote){
            TextView post_quote = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_quote);
            post_quote.setText(Quote);
        }

        public void setQuoteAuthor(String QuoteAuthor){
            TextView post_quoteAuthor = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
            post_quoteAuthor.setText(QuoteAuthor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You set Layout manager two time. I thinks this cause show error

Comment: Remove below Code:
 final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RecyclerView` wasn't assigned yet, swap these:

```
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewQuote);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write code like this, you first need to initialise the recyclerview before Linear Layout Manager.

```
 mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewQuote);

 final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Thank you buddy.. Thanks a lot forr the help :)

Comment: Most Welcome Prateek

Comment: can you able to solve it.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139666/fetching-image-from-firebase-using-picasso)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening when `LinearLayout` is unable to find the `RecyclerView` in your layout.
You have to add `RecyclerView` in in your layout file where the lists are going to be displayed,
or else the created `RecyclerView` was wrongly mentioned when using `findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewID)` or `RecyclerView` was not mentioned.